# Understanding Datasheets for Microchip Explorer 16 Board (and PIC32MX360F512L MCU)

Tags: embedded

I'm working my way through a book ("Programming 32-bit Microcontrollers in C: Exploring the PIC32", by Lucio Di Jasio, 2008) which uses the Explorer 16 Dev Board by Microchip.

I have the DM240001 revision of this board, and a PIM (Plug-In Module) PIC32MX360F512L microcontroller installed. [image: DM240001 Explorer 16 Dev Board]

One project in the book deals with a simple program that blinks some LEDs (the PIC32MX peripheral PortA is comprised of 8 external pins, RA0 through RA7, which are connected to eight LEDs on the Dev Board, so when writing a digital 1 to one of these pins, the LED should light up) on and off once per second.

The project uses another peripheral, Timer1, to achieve the timing needed to blink the LEDs at this rate. This timer can be set to use either an on-chip (internal) oscillator as it's timing source, or an external oscillator (which would be on the Explorer 16 Dev Board in this case, if I understand this correctly).

The Timer1 peripheral is only a 16-bit timer, so it has a pre-scaler (1, 8, 64, or 256) which extends the range of the timer (so using a 256 prescaler effectively converts the 65,536 tick timer
into a 65536 x 256 = 16,777,216 tick timer).

The book's code seems to be wrong in practice however. The book suggests using a prescaler of 256 and a delay of 144000 in order to pause for 1 second. They assume a "36 MHz peripheral bus clock frequency", which doesn't seem correct to me - at least, I can't find a reference to that anywhere in the documentation (the User Guide for the Explorer 16 board, the PIC32MX360F512L datasheet or PIC32MX Family Reference Guide).

I have some questions I hope you can help with:

1. What does the Timer1 peripheral use as its default timing source, on the PIC32MX360F512L? Is this internal to the chip itself?
2. What does the Explorer 16 Dev Board have as an external timing source for Timer1 to select, if desired?

I ended up using the code below to give me the desired effect. I got the LEDs to toggle once every second by setting the prescaler to maximum (256) and using a delay value of 1990. So doing the math:

```
        1990 x 256 = 509,440 Hz (or about 510 kHz)
```

My best guess is that whatever the Timer1 is using for an external clock, it runs somewhere around this frequency (510kHz), but I can't find reference to this value anywhere in the documentation.

Here's my project code:

```
/*
 * Loops (Project 2)
 */
  
 #include <p32xxxx.h>
 
 #define DELAY 1990
 
 main() {
 
     // initialization
     DDPCONbits.JTAGEN = 0;   // disable JTAG port, free up PORT A
     TRISA = 0xff00;          // set all PORT A pins to OUTPUT
     T1CON = 0x8030;          // TMR1 on, prescale 1:256           (1000 0000 0011 0000)
     PR1 = 0xFFFF;            // set period register to max
 
     // main loop
     while(1) {
     
         // turn on some LEDs
         PORTA = 0xff;  // turn pins 0-7 on, Port A
         TMR1 = 0;      // reset 16-bit timer, Timer1
         while (TMR1 < DELAY) ; // do nothing

         // turn off all LEDs
         PORTA = 0x00;     // turn all pins off
         TMR1 = 0;      // reset 16-bit timer, Timer1
         while (TMR1 < DELAY) ; // do nothing
     }
 }
```

I've found that when doing embedded programming, one of the biggest challenges is getting detailed information on things like this out of datasheets and family references that can number in the 1000s of pages (usually because companies like Microchip lump together all their products into one enormous Family Reference, or lump together a series of chips into Datasheets - making them huge and probably more error prone due to the number of variations they need to keep track of).

Comment: If I were to answer this question, I too would have to peruse the extensive documentation. I’d start at the section on ‘Clocks’. Most of these modern microcontrollers have an internal oscillator to start up with and your code can select from various clocking schemes. Unless there is hidden startup code, you could assume it is running from the default internal oscillator. The frequency of this should be explicitly stated. Then you can look for the clock tree diagram to see how the peripherals are clocked. This investigation should allow you to answer your question.

Comment: @dvanaria - The previous comment is spot on.  Reading and comprehending datasheets is one of the many challenges of embedded programming.  Whenever I start a project using a microcontroller I have not used before, I always start with the clocks.

Comment: Ok, from the Product Features listed on Microchip's website for the  PIC32MX360F512L, it shows the following:

    "80MHz/105DMIPS, 32-bit MIPS M4K Core" and 
   "2 Internal oscillators (8MHz & 31KHz)"

So I'm assuming It's using an 8 MHz internal oscillator by default, even though the "PIC32MX3xx/4xx Data Sheet" doesn't mention that value specifically. I'm basing this off the assumption that Timer1 uses the PBCLK signal by default in the PIC32MX360F512L. I'll keep digging into the documentation and experimenting and if I can figure out something definitive I'll post my own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the answer to all this. The IDE supplied by Microchip (I'm using MPLAB IDE v8.91) has a menu setting to configure the PIC32's startup configuration, specifically which oscillators to turn on and off, what to set the multipliers and dividers to that make up the Primary Oscillator Clock Chain (which takes in an external 8 MHz clock source and divides it by 2, then sets a PLL to multiply it by 18) to produce the System Clock (which in my case is 72 MHz). Further downstream, a Peripheral Bus Clock is set, based off the System Clock. The book calls for this to be 1/2 the System Clock.

So in short, the answer I was looking for, was that the PIC32MX microcontroller (like all microcontrollers) have a certain startup configuration for all the main functions of the chip. This configuration is stored in the chip's non-volatile Flash memory, but it can be viewed/edited using an IDE's menu settings.

The book I'm working through says how to set the default, startup data. I had failed to realize that this was something that had to be configured through an IDE menu.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, but it was still mostly by trial and error. I can't find the exact values of SYSCLK and PBCLK anywhere in the Microchip documentation for the PIC32MX 300 series chips, but here is what I did find out and was able to devise:

The T1CON register has TCS set to 0, which selects an internal oscillator
in the PIC32MX chip. TGATE is set to 0 also, and the multiplexer shown
in the Type A Timer Block Diagram (PIC32 Family Reference Manual) shows
that this combination (TCS=0 and TGATE=0) will use the PBCLK clock,
which I believe stands for Peripheral Bus Clock.

Then on page 6-6 of the PIC32MX Family Reference Manual (Section 6 Oscillators)
it shows the following:
PBDIV
11 = PBCLK is SYSCLK divided by 8 (default)

It appears that the PIC32MX360F512L is (by default) using a SYSCLK of 4 MHz,
making PBCLK = 500 kHz (4 MHz / 8).

```
If the clock ticks 500,000 times per second...
500000/256 =   1953  (prescaler = 3)
500000/64  =   7812  (prescaler = 2)
500000/8   =  62500  (prescaler = 1)
```

So here is a working solution to blink the LEDs on and off every 1 second on the Explorer 16 Dev Board (rev DM240001) with a plug-in module PIC32MX360F512L MCU:

```
#include <p32xxxx.h>

#define DELAY 7812

main() {

    // initialization
    DDPCONbits.JTAGEN = 0;   // disable JTAG port, free up PORT A
    TRISA = 0xff00;          // set all PORT A pins to OUTPUT
    T1CON = 0x8020;          // TMR1 on, Prescaler 1:64 = 2
    PR1 = 0xFFFF;            // set period register to max

    // main loop
    while(1) {
    
        // turn on some LEDs
        PORTA = 0xff;  // turn pins 0-7 on, Port A
        TMR1 = 0;      // reset 16-bit timer, Timer1
        while (TMR1 < DELAY) ; // do nothing

        // turn off all LEDs
        PORTA = 0x00;     // turn all pins off
        TMR1 = 0;      // reset 16-bit timer, Timer1
        while (TMR1 < DELAY) ; // do nothing
    }
}
```